# Android: button is not changing to pause state when i click

Tags: java, android, url, android-emulator, media-player

i have coded for media player and it is playing song .In the front end only image button is used and hardcoded as play button

when i click again it has to change image to pause state but the button which i have used is playing the song two times simultaneously whenever i click on it which is wrong

but i need the song to be paused so whereever i used

```
mp.start();
```

function which will be start to play the music from the url i added the code as

```
if(!mp.isPlaying()){
mp.start();
buttonPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
}else {
mp.pause();
buttonPlayPause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);}
```

but when i click the play button it starts playing and again if i click the button again it starts playing two times simultaneously

please help me how should i start and pause the mp3 file which i have displayed it in url it is not going to else block itself should i use different function

the full code of the project is

```
public class MainActivity5 extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener {



MediaPlayer mp;
ProgressDialog pd;
Button bt;
ImageButton iv;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main5);
iv = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
iv.setOnClickListener(this);}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
 {
   Log.i("StreamAudioDemo", "prepare finished");
   //pd.setMessage("Playing.....");
   //mp.start();

   /*if(mp.isPlaying()== true)
   {
       mp.start();
       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
   }
   else 
   {
       mp.pause();
       mp.release();
       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
   }*/

}
@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

   try
    {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Buffering.....");
        //pd.show();
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mp.setDataSource("http://192.168.1.138/Android/music/vande.mp3");
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("StreamAudioDemo", e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
  pd.dismiss();
  return false;
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    pd.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
}}
```

thanks for your help in advance

i have commented some code above i have to re correct it

Comment: what is this `mp` and `mediaPlayer` in your code, is that a typo or your are using as given here ??

Comment: you created MediaPlayer object as mp and in else condition you are using as mediaPlayer

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (mp.isPlaying()) {`?

Comment: @NARESHREDDY i have edited check and let me know

Comment: @EgorN OR INSTEAD of using BackgroundResource i have to use ImageResource

Comment: If `buttonPlayPause` is an `ImageButton`, then yes - you should use `setImageResource`.

Comment: Is it working now or not. If not what is the problem

Comment: use `if(mp.isPlaying()== true)` instead of this `if(!mp.isPlaying())`

Comment: @Sree code is working but it is playing simultaneously 2 to 3 times whenever i click the pause button also it is playing

Comment: can you able to post your full code on media player

Comment: @Sree ya sure i will edit the upper code itself and post full code

Comment: @Sree i have posted the whole code which is working code

Comment: look you are starting  mp.start(); before the if condition, so remove that and it will work

Comment: if i remove also it is not working bro @Sree

Comment: ya i checked bro but even if i click it is repeating two times @Sree

Comment: only two times, no idea why it play two times.Please debug the app and find out the flow of control of the app, you can surly understand why this happan

Comment: no no when i click the button more than 1 time it plays the same mp3 file two times @Sree ya i will try it

Answer (score 0):

you can have a try at your onclickListener,when this player is playing,if you want to pause it ,you should to call MediaPlayer.pause() ,if you want to release it data,you can call MediaPlayer.release(),then ,you can play next music.

Comment: when should i use release() in this above code @tagmic

Comment: this can to help you?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
 {
   Log.i("StreamAudioDemo", "prepare finished");
   //pd.setMessage("Playing.....");

// mp.start(); - this should be removed 
   if(mp.isPlaying()== true)
   {
     mp.pause();

       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
   }
   else 
   {
      mp.start();
       mp.release();
       iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
   }

}
```

Comment: k i will try and let you know in a minute @Sree